# Added plus sign before number input in angularjs

Tags: regex, angularjs, input, numbers, directive

I am using this directive to keep user typing only number into input tag.

```
   app.directive('validNumber', function () {
            return {
                require: '?ngModel',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                    if (!ngModelCtrl) {
                        return;
                    }

                    ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (val) {
                        if (angular.isUndefined(val)) {
                            var val = '';
                        }
                        var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
                        var decimalCheck = clean.split('.');

                        if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[0])) {
                            decimalCheck[0] = decimalCheck[0].slice(0, 10);
                            if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                                clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
                            }
                            else { 
                                clean = decimalCheck[0];
                            }
                            //console.log(decimalCheck[0][0]);
                        }

                        if (!angular.isUndefined(decimalCheck[1])) {
                            decimalCheck[1] = decimalCheck[1].slice(0, 3);
                            clean = decimalCheck[0] + '.' + decimalCheck[1];
                        }

                        if (val !== clean) {
                            ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(clean);
                            ngModelCtrl.$render();
                        }
                        return clean;
                    });

                    element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        });
```

But now i want to custome this, that means user can type ONLY ONE of "+" or "-" in the first. I think i have to change this pattern of

```
var clean = val.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, '');
```

i also try to change into val.replace(/[^0-9.+-]/g, ''). It works but incorrectly, with this pattern user can type more "+" and "-" in any position of input field. I just wanna keep user typing ONLY ONE of "+" or "-" in the first like "+1234" or "-1234"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a regex problem than an AngularJS one, so you might have more luck there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex

I'll try help you though. I think the regex you want matches a single +-, then any number of digits, then optionally a decimal point, then any number of digits. A single regex to match that is:

```
^[+-]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*
```

Have a read about groups and the '?' operator. This regex allows:

```
+.
-.
```

which don't make sense as input. You could design clever regexes to omit those results, but I think it would be easier to check the entry programmatically.

Finally, there are also very likely regexes online to help you solve any regex problem you ever come across more comprehensivley than you could. Just google an english description next time, and check out this for what you want:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html